# python flask - flask/bin/python is a "bad interpreter" after changing project name; have to use flask/bin/python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, interpreter

I decided to change the name of my Flask project folder from microblog to finalproject. I am using Python 3.4.2 on a Mac.

Here's the hierarchy of finalproject:

```
Vivians-MacBook-Pro:finalproject vivianli$ ls
__pycache__ app.db      db_create.py    db_migrate.py   db_upgrade.py   run.py
app     config.py   db_downgrade.py db_repository   flask       tmp
```

Since then (and I should have thought this through more  carefully before I did this), the path "flask/bin/python" no longer works. For example,

```
Vivians-MacBook-Pro:finalproject vivianli$ ./db_migrate.py
-bash: ./db_migrate.py: flask/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

db_migrate.py is a migrating script that I've granted permission to. However when I use flask/bin/python3, it works.

My question is why flask/bin/python doesn't work anymore, why flask/bin/python3 does after changing my overall project name, and if there are any other settings I should be concerned about.

Comment: Can you confirm that flask folder is basically your virtualenv? if it is you just need to activate the virtualenv by typing `source flask/bin/active`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure flask is the virtualenv. I used the command you suggested (it's actually flask/bin/activate) and it seems that it activate properly. However, strangely when I try to run something like ./run.py (the file that kicks the server up, gets the site running) it keeps trying to use the old 'flask/bin/python' instead of what actually works, 'flask/bin/python3'. The question now is how to reroute this.

Comment: Just more detail, ./run.py definitely works fine, and sits in the app directory under finalproject.

Comment: Python is linked to python2 in your virtualenv because that's what was defined in a requirements.txt or your systems default python. You must have written your code in python 3? Flask is most compatible with python 2 so you might want to change your code instead or delete the virtualenv and create it again with python3.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got killed a link to python executable. Seems you are using virtualenv: try to recreate it like this:

```
rm -rf flask
virtualenv --clear flask
```

Or, if you don't want to do that, you can remake link to python executable

```
cd ./flask/bin
rm -rf python
ln -s <location, where the python is installed>/python ./
```

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a virtual environnement located in the `./flask` folder, so have a look at the `flask/bin` folder and pick a python interpreter.

First make sure you have activated the virtual environment by launching

```
$ source ./flask/bin/activate
```

Also check for your interpreter in `./flask/bin/python`

```
$ ls -lsa ./flask/bin/
```

You should find here `python3.4` or something similar and `python` pointing on it, about like this :

```
 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 fx fx     9 31 mai   14:29 python -> python3.4
 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 fx fx     9 31 mai   14:29 python3 -> python3.4
12 -rwxr-xr-x 1 fx fx 10440 31 mai   14:29 python3.4
```

If not, you might need to make a symbolic link from python3 to python in your virtual environment to avoid finding the same problem in other scripts of the project.

```
$ cd ./flask/bin
$ ln -s ./python3 ./python
```

This might fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like flask was not finding python in the venv. In the flask/bin folder deleted both python, python3 folders

Recreated the link to python3

```
$ ln -s <{python Installed Path}>/python3 ./
$ ln -s ./python3 ./python
```

Thenter code hereis worked for me.